# Strange fine structure splitting of the two-body Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, atomic-physics, dirac-equation, hydrogen

This question is a follow-up of the [discussion about one of my answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/784534/201598).

Marsch proposed a two-body Dirac equation for hydrogen in order to treat the proton recoil effects in a non-perturbative way (*Ann. Phys.* **14 5** 324 (2005); [link to the PDF of the original paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/andp.20055170505?casa_token=ydtTYIWbQwoAAAAA:FyM1-Mb6aLwTeyQaH0Iq7ZhBesaCcoa1uOszObI4By3pVspqm9laJMw5LomWPNimqFlSe1lEfLw_YrC6); [link to the PDF of the erratum](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/andp.20065180604)). His main result is the analytic rest frame energy formula
$$
{\cal{E}}_{nk}=M\left[1-\frac{2\mu}{M}+\frac{2\mu}{M}\left(1+\frac{(Z\alpha)^2}{\left(\sqrt{k^2-\frac{1}{4}(Z\alpha)^2}+n-|k|\right)^2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \ ,
$$
where
$$
M=m_{\text{e}}+m_{\text{P}} \ \ \ , \ \ \ 
\mu=\frac{m_{\text{e}}m_{\text{P}}}{m_{\text{e}}+m_{\text{P}}}
$$
are the total and reduced masses, respectively, and $n=1,2,...$ is the principal quantum number. The angular momentum quantum number is either $k=1$ (when electron and proton spins are coupled to a singlet), or $k=\pm1,\pm2,...$ (for $J_{\text{tot}}=L\pm1$ in case of triplet spin coupling). After expanding to $\mathcal{O}(\alpha^4)$, one finds (cf. Eq. (97) of the paper)
$$
{\cal{E}}_{nk}\approx M-\frac{\mu(Z\alpha)^2}{2n^2}-\frac{\mu(Z\alpha)^4}{2n^3}\left[\frac{1}{4|k|}-\frac{3}{4n}+\frac{1}{4n}\frac{\mu}{M}\right] \ , 
$$
which should be compared to the perturbative fine structure formula (cf. Eq. (37) of [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0002158)):
$$
E_{nj}\approx M-\frac{\mu(Z\alpha)^2}{2n^2}-\frac{\mu(Z\alpha)^4}{2n^3}\left[\frac{1}{j+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{3}{4n}+\frac{1}{4n}\frac{\mu}{M}\right] \ .
$$
Here, of course $j=L\pm1/2$. My problem is that these two formulae seem to predict rather different fine structure splittings:
$$
\Delta\mathcal{E}_{n,k_1k_2}\approx-\frac{\mu(Z\alpha)^4}{2n^3}\left[\frac{1}{4|k_2|}-\frac{1}{4|k_1|}\right]
\ \ \ \leftrightarrow \ \ \
\Delta E_{n,j_1j_2}\approx-\frac{\mu(Z\alpha)^4}{2n^3}\left[\frac{1}{j_2+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{j_1+\frac{1}{2}}\right] \ .
$$
For e.g. the $2p_{1/2}$, $2p_{3/2}$ states of hydrogen, the traditional formula gives
$$
\Delta E_{2,\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}}\approx\frac{\mu\alpha^4}{16}\frac{1}{2}\approx
0.365 \, {\text{cm}}^{-1} \ ,
$$
which agrees nicely with the [NIST value](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl?de=0&spectrum=H+I&submit=Retrieve+Data&units=0&format=0&output=0&page_size=15&multiplet_ordered=0&conf_out=on&term_out=on&level_out=on&unc_out=1&j_out=on&lande_out=on&perc_out=on&biblio=on&temp=) $0.366 \, {\text{cm}}^{-1}$. On the other hand, no $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ can be found that would yield an even remotely similar value for $\Delta\mathcal{E}_{2,k_1k_2}$. The author actually comments on the difference between $\mathcal{E}_{nk}$ and $E_{nj}$ below his Eq. (98), but his remark suggests that it is the perturbative formula that lacks some effects associated with the proton spin. I find this strange, because I would expect proton spin effects to be very small, due to the large mass of the proton (hyperfine structure is $\mathcal{O}(m_{\text{e}}\alpha(Z\alpha)^3m_{\text{e}}/m_{\text{P}})$ at best). Another weird issue is that in the perturbative formula, $j$ emerges from the coupling between the spin of the electron and the orbital angular momentum irrespective of the proton spin; the coupling between electron and proton spins is visible only in the tiny hyperfine splitting. For example, the $F=1$ hyperfine branch of $2p_{1/2}$ corresponds to a singlet spin-pair coupled to the $l=1$ orbital angular momentum, as
$$ 
F=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \ .
$$
Contrary to this, such a spin coupling seems to have a much more drastic effect in the two-body model, as a singlet spin-pair would lead uniformly to $k=1$, essentially killing off the fine structure.

Only the Coulomb interaction is treated in the two-body equation, while the Breit interaction is left out. However, this cannot be the solution of my problem, since the Breit interaction only adds recoil corrections to the fine structure, and the discrepancy persists even as $m_{\text{e}}/m_{\text{P}}\rightarrow0$.

So, my questions are the following. Do I misunderstand the $\mathcal{E}_{nk}$ formula, or it really cannot describe properly the fine structure splitting? If I am wrong, then what is the correct interpretation/usage of $\mathcal{E}_{nk}$ and $k$, and how to reconcile $\mathcal{E}_{nk}$ with $E_{nj}$?